# Configuration for Database Connection

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, appsettings, dbset

Please I'm new to C# and I've been trying to configure my code to work with a database. I need a proper and step by step guide on how to go about it. Thanks

I have created a class that inherits from Dbcontext and also configured it in program.cs but when I opened package manager console and typed in "add-migration AddRazortoDb" (Razor  is my project name) the error report is " Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'

Comment: It may help if you could provide the minimal codes that could reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

nuget packages : ef server,ef tool,ef core
connection string for sql server :

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"server=DESKTOP-CV0FSTJ\SQLEXPRESS;database=DBName;trusted_connection=true;");
}